# `xor` function in R

Tags: r, xor, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to work through the code in a bootstrap simulation on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/193997/67822) with two major hurdles. First, the few times I have played with bootstrapping, I have done it without using the `{boot}` package, and relying on functions like `replicate`, or simply loops. And second, and the main object of my question, I don't know what the function `xor` takes in as inputs, and what it ultimately does:

```
n <- 1000
dat <- c("A", rep("B", n-1))
indicator <- function(x, ndx)   xor("A"%in%x[ndx], TRUE)
```

I see that it assesses whether `"A"` is in `x` and returns `FALSE` if it actually is in it. The issue comes with the input `ndx`. It probably stands for "index", and this is likely connected with the bootstrapping that follows:

```
p_hat <- function(dat, m=1e3){
    foo <- boot(data=dat, statistic=indicator, R=m) 
    1/mean(foo$t)
} 

reps <- replicate(100, p_hat(dat))
```

But how? What in this last chunk of code feeds the `ndx` in the first chunk?

Comment: `xor(a,TRUE)` is logically equivalent to `!a`

Comment: I thought so. And where does the `ndx` part comes from?

Comment: isn't it the second argument of the function?  I think the name of the function is specified in the statistic attribute of boot, which it internally resolves and calls with the corresponding arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So the `foo` function "supplies" the arguments that `indicator` needs: `x` (in this case `dat`), and `ndx`. I see where `x` comes from: `dat`, but I can't see where `ndx` originates, or what role it plays in `indicator`.

Comment: My guess It's a dynamic dispatch, sorry but I have no further info.